# android left join query with room

Tags: android, database, android-room, kotlin-android-extensions

I am trying to change my sqlite database with room library. I am little confuse with left join query.

I have implemented it with sqlite, but don't know how can I achieve same withh room?

Here is my table creation:

**first table: Notification**

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE_NAME ($COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $ICON TEXT, $TITLE INTEGER," +
                " $DATE INTEGER, $TYPE INTEGER,$URL TEXT, $MESSAGE INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY($TITLE) REFERENCES ${TableNotificationsTrans.getTableName(this)}(id)," +
                "FOREIGN KEY($MESSAGE) REFERENCES ${TableNotificationsTrans.getTableName(this)}(id))")
```

**second table: Notification_Trans**

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE_NAME ($COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, $COLUMN_EN TEXT, $COLUMN_GU TEXT, $COLUMN_HI TEXT)")
```

What I am doing is I am storing notification in **notification** table but its name and description will be stored with specific language, in **notification_trans**.

**Query to achieve**

```
DatabaseHelper.database!!.rawQuery("SELECT A.$COLUMN_ID, A.$ICON, N.${language.toLowerCase()} $TITLE, A.$DATE, A.$TYPE, A.$URL, M.${language.toLowerCase()} $MESSAGE FROM $TABLE_NAME A LEFT JOIN NotificationsTrans N ON A.$TITLE = N.id LEFT JOIN NotificationsTrans M ON A.$MESSAGE = M.id ORDER BY $DATE DESC LIMIT $pageNum*10, 10", null)
```

**Question**

```
How can I achieve same with room?
```

**Edit**

My application is multi-language application, where I am getting notification title with specific language, like Hindi or Gujarati. I am storing notification details in **notification** table, while title in **notification_trans**.

NotificationTrans have column with id, english, hindi, gujarati.

When user asked for gujarati, I am retriving notification title from notificationTrans's column gujarati.

I am able do so, in sqlite.

But now I want it with Room

Comment: If you had a static query, you would use it in Room exactly the same as you use it with SQLite. In your case, you are using string interpolation to generate the query, in which case Room cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

**#1** - Need to create a model class that matches with the result of the query

```
data class ClientAndCity(
     @ColumnInfo(name="id") val id: Long,
     @ColumnInfo(name="client_name") val clientName: String?,
     @ColumnInfo(name="city_name") val cityName: String?
)
```

**#2** - Inside your DAO create your query

```
@Query("SELECT clients.id, clients.name AS client_name, cities.name AS city_name FROM clients LEFT JOIN cities ON cities.id = clients.city_id WHERE clientes.id = :clientId")
fun getClientAndHisCity(clientId: Long): ClientAndCity?
```

**#3** - Use you function

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{
     val result: ClientAndCity = clientDAO.getClientAndHisCity(clientId)
     //do something with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First You have to make the model classes for both, You may have already declared them , You just need to make a few changes if they already exists.

```
   @Entity
public class Notification {
    @PrimaryKey
    int id;
    String icon;
    @ForeignKey(entity = Notification_Trans.class, parentColumns = "col_id", childColumns = "id")
    String title;
    int date;
    int type;
    String url;
    int msg;

}

    @Entity
public class Notification_Trans {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int col_id;
    String column_en;
    String column_gu;
    String column_hi;
```

This makes for your POJO, I couldn't understand your Foreign key constraints, so Pardon me for that, you can make changes as you see fit.
You can Declare your DAO as per this`
@Dao

```
public interface DAO {

    @Query("SELECT note.id, note.title, note.description, category.name as categoryName " +
            "FROM note " +
            "LEFT JOIN category ON note.category_id = category.id")
    List getCategoryNotes();

}
`
```

I haven't made changes in the query, which I found at [Link here](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/android-architecture-components-room-persistence-library). As your query was a complex one, But, it'll give you an Idea about how to do that.,
After this, You just need to access your Dao interface from your Database class object, which will handle the creation & all other things room, like this one below`

```
@Database(entities = {Notification.class, NotificationTrans.class}, version = 3)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static AppDatabase instance;

    public static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance =
                    Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "database_name")
                            // allow queries on the main thread.
                            // Don't do this on a real app! See PersistenceBasicSample for an example.
                            //.allowMainThreadQueries()
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static void destroyInstance() {

        instance = null;
    }

    public abstract Dao notificationDao();
```

It helps creating a separate class for Database, & keeping track of object from it.
& you can access your data with `AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(context).notificationDao().yourQueryMethodName();`

You may require to refer to [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a) to understand the relations between room, & implement your requirement,

EDIT 1:
Here's how your DAO should look like ,`

```
@Insert
void insert(Notifications object);
```

//This will insert a single Item

```
 @Insert
 void insertAll(Notifications... objects);
```

While this can enter a list of Data,

You can call this methods with your Database object, like`AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(context).notificationDao().yourQueryMethodName()` here instead of `yourQueryMethod()`, if you call `insert()` & pass the object you need to store in the database, It'll do it,

For E.g.`db.parcelDao().insert(parcel);` 
this is how I insert Data in my ParcelDao, db  is Database object, & parcel is the object of data need to be stored. One more thing, you can't call this method on main thread, so you may need to use Handler or AsyncTask for the purpose, Sorry I forgot to mention that.
Have a look at Room [Training at Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html) for implementation of basic functionality of room

Comment: Please give detailed answer.. How can I insert

Comment: Let me know what you didn't understand, & i'll try to elaborate that part

Comment: How can I insert value in database with that?

Comment: this will not insert in trans table

Comment: You can  make similar method for trans table, you just need to create a similar Dao for that class too, refer https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html for more,

Comment: I know that, but I want automatic insertion

Comment: What you mean by automatic? Currently, Room doesn't support custom insertion queries in the @Query, So, you have to call your insert methods together & the data will be added, If that's not what you mean, Clarify me

Comment: If i may intervene, what i think he wants to say from that is You are trying to insert data in one table, but the table which has the foreign key and stuff, how would the data get inserted into that, cant we do that automatically, because whats the use of defining foreign constraints, if we have to do it manually

Comment: what about transaction?

Comment: The answer was 2 years old, Room has evolved a lot. And, I didn't keep track of it since I switched technologies. I'll suggest you refer to the official documentation for the answer