# How to save the below json data into two tables(model table and variant table) and get the data according to model

Tags: android, join, inner-join, android-room

I am facing issue with inserting data in sqlite. I am using room for this. I need to join the table to get the data. below is the json data which I need to insert data

```
[{
    "ImgPath": "",
    "ModelCode": "Model 1",
    "ModelDescription": "Model 1",
    "ModelID": "1",
    "VarientList": [{
        "MDescription": "APOLLO BLU",
        "MDescriptionLong": "APOLLO BLU",
        "MaterialID": "1",
        "MaterialImgPath": "",
        "Mcode": "APOLOL/CRSP/BLU",
        "ModelColor": ""
    }, {
        "MDescription": "APOLLO BLK",
        "MDescriptionLong": "APOLLO BLK",
        "MaterialID": "2",
        "MaterialImgPath": "",
        "Mcode": "APOLOL/CRSP/BLK",
        "ModelColor": ""
    }]
}, {
    "ImgPath": "",
    "ModelCode": "Model 2",
    "ModelDescription": "Model 2",
    "ModelID": "2",
    "VarientList": [{
        "MDescription": "SACE BROWN",
        "MDescriptionLong": "SACE BROWN",
        "MaterialID": "3",
        "MaterialImgPath": "",
        "Mcode": "SACE/BRN",
        "ModelColor": ""
    }, {
        "MDescription": "SACE BLU",
        "MDescriptionLong": "SACE BLU",
        "MaterialID": "4",
        "MaterialImgPath": "",
        "Mcode": "SACE/BLU",
        "ModelColor": ""
    }]
}]
```

I have taken this as reference to do this 
https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a

but I am a bit confused to insert and get the data from join table. What are the attributes will be the foreign keys and how to write the jointable for this.

//This is my Item table constructor

```
public ItemTable(String modelID, String modelCode, String modelDescription, String imgPath) {
        this.modelID = modelID;
        this.modelCode = modelCode;
        this.modelDescription = modelDescription;
        this.imgPath = imgPath;

    }
```

//This is my Variant table constructor

```
public VariantTable(String MDescription, String MDescriptionLong, String MaterialID, String imgPath,, String Mcode,String Mcode) {
        this.MDescription = MDescription;
        this.MDescriptionLong = MDescriptionLong;
        this.MaterialID = MaterialID;
        this.Mcode = Mcode;
    this.ModelColor = ModelColor;

    }
```

I want to insert model in one table and variants of that model in second table.And I need to show the variant details as per the model. For example, If I have selected Model1 then the variants of the model1 has to come in a drop down. 
how to show like that,  how can i do this?

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: I am confused to insert data using join table. what will be my join table and how to get the variants of a selected model

Comment: I think this will helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47920930/10989990

Comment: for Join you need to keep primary foriegn key relation, i guess in variant table you need to add model ID as well , then you can join both the table using model id

Comment: @NehaRathore can u please describe more with an example , as I am new to room and this join concept

Comment: see my answer, where you can get some fields from model table and also all the variants associated with the same modelID

Answer (score 0):

this will help you to get data from DB

```
@Query("SELECT model.ModelCode, model.ModelID, model.ModelDescription, varient.MDescription as MDescription " +
            "FROM model " +
            "LEFT JOIN varient ON model.ModelID = varient.ModelID")
    List getModelsWithVarient();
```

**EDIT**

first of all create model for your json

```
@Entity
public class MyModel {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String modelID;
    private String imgPath;
    private String modelCode;
    private String modelDescription;

    @Ignore
    private List<VarientList> varientList = null;

    public String getImgPath() {
        return imgPath;
    }

    public void setImgPath(String imgPath) {
        this.imgPath = imgPath;
    }

    public String getModelCode() {
        return modelCode;
    }

    public void setModelCode(String modelCode) {
        this.modelCode = modelCode;
    }

    public String getModelDescription() {
        return modelDescription;
    }

    public void setModelDescription(String modelDescription) {
        this.modelDescription = modelDescription;
    }

    public String getModelID() {
        return modelID;
    }

    public void setModelID(String modelID) {
        this.modelID = modelID;
    }

    public List<VarientList> getVarientList() {
        return varientList;
    }

    public void setVarientList(List<VarientList> varientList) {
        this.varientList = varientList;
    }

}
```

and one model for Varient

```
@Entity(foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = MyModel.class, parentColumns = "modelID", childColumns = "id"))
public class VarientList {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int id;

    String modelID;

    private String mDescription;
    private String mDescriptionLong;
    private String materialID;
    private String materialImgPath;
    private String mcode;
    private String modelColor;

    public String getMDescription() {
        return mDescription;
    }

    public void setMDescription(String mDescription) {
        this.mDescription = mDescription;
    }

    public String getMDescriptionLong() {
        return mDescriptionLong;
    }

    public void setMDescriptionLong(String mDescriptionLong) {
        this.mDescriptionLong = mDescriptionLong;
    }

    public String getMaterialID() {
        return materialID;
    }

    public void setMaterialID(String materialID) {
        this.materialID = materialID;
    }

    public String getMaterialImgPath() {
        return materialImgPath;
    }

    public void setMaterialImgPath(String materialImgPath) {
        this.materialImgPath = materialImgPath;
    }

    public String getMcode() {
        return mcode;
    }

    public void setMcode(String mcode) {
        this.mcode = mcode;
    }

    public String getModelColor() {
        return modelColor;
    }

    public void setModelColor(String modelColor) {
        this.modelColor = modelColor;
    }

}
```

now make one DAO interface to perform all the queries on db

```
@Dao
public interface MyModelDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(MyModel myModel);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM MyModel WHERE modelID=:modelID")
    List<MyModel> findAllModels(final int modelID);

    @Query("SELECT MyModel.ModelCode, " +
        "MyModel.ModelID, " +
        "MyModel.ModelDescription, " +
        "MyModel.imgPath, " +
        "VarientList.MDescription as MDescription, " +
        "VarientList.mDescriptionLong as mDescriptionLong, " +
        "VarientList.materialID as materialID, " +
        "VarientList.materialImgPath as materialImgPath, " +
        "VarientList.mcode as mcode, " +
        "VarientList.modelColor as modelColor " +
        "FROM model " +
        "LEFT JOIN VarientList ON MyModel.ModelID = VarientList.ModelID")
    List<MyModel> getModelsWithVarientList();
}
```

now call insert method to insert record and pass the complete model into  it.

to get all the varients from the model call `getModelsWithVarientList()` this will retruns all the models stored in db

Comment: please tell me how to insert first

Comment: for more you can also refer this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667160/android-room-insert-relation-entities-using-room

Comment: thanks for the help will try it and let you know once I done with it.