# Having 2 model class(dataClass) in adapter(ListAdapter)

Tags: android, database, kotlin, join, android-recyclerview

Recently, I was faced with an issue that is a bit hard for me to solve

I need to put 2 models in the List adapter, but it always says 2 types of arguments expected

[Here is the Link of the whole project](https://github.com/AmirAndroidDeveloper/Holy-Quran)

and I want to have Transaction and Bank models in ListAdapter

you can read the project README.
The adapter that I want to have 2 models is in ui.TransactionHistory

[image: Image of the code and error]

here is my whole adapter class:

```
    class TransactionHistory() :
        ListAdapter<Transaction, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(BillDiffCallback()) {
        private val ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY = 0
        private val ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM = 1
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            return when (viewType) {
                ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM -> ViewHolder.from(parent)
                ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY -> EmptyViewHolder.from(parent)
                else -> throw ClassCastException("Unknown viewType $viewType")
            }
        }
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is ViewHolder -> {
                val item = getItem(position)
                holder.bind(item, clickListener)
//                holder.bind2(Bank, clickListener)
            }
            is EmptyViewHolder -> {
                holder.bind()
            }
        }
    }

    lateinit var clickListener: AdapterListener2
    fun setOnclickListener(listener: AdapterListener2) {
        clickListener = listener
    }


    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return if (itemCount > 0)
            ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM
        else
            ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY
    }

    class ViewHolder
    private constructor(val binding: ItemUserTransactionListBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: Transaction, adapterListener2: AdapterListener2) {
            binding.transaction = item
            binding.clickListener = adapterListener2
            binding.executePendingBindings()
            if (item.type == "payPayment") {
                binding.transactionStatus.text = "برداخت قسط"
            } else if (item.type == "decrease") {
                binding.transactionStatus.text = "برداشت"
            } else if (item.type == "increase") {
                binding.transactionStatus.text = "واریز"
            }

            if (item.decrease == null) {
                binding.amount.text = item.increase
            } else {
                binding.amount.text = item.decrease
            }
        }

        fun bind2(item2: Bank, adapterListener2: AdapterListener2) {
            binding.bankInfo = item2
            binding.clickListener = adapterListener2
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = ItemUserTransactionListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }
}

class EmptyViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ItemUserTransactionListBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind() {
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }

    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): EmptyViewHolder {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding = ItemUserTransactionListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
            return EmptyViewHolder(binding)
        }
    }
}


class BillDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Transaction>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Transaction, newItem: Transaction): Boolean {
        return oldItem.transId == newItem.transId
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(
        oldItem: Transaction,
        newItem: Transaction
    ): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}

class AdapterListener2(
    val clickListener: (id: Long?) -> Unit,
    val deleteListener: (category: Transaction) -> Unit

) {
    fun onclick(transaction: Transaction) = clickListener(transaction.userId)
    fun onDeleteClick(userInfo: Transaction) = deleteListener(userInfo)

}
```

whenever i placed secound model here:

```
 ListAdapter<Transaction, **Bank**, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(BillDiffCallback()) {}
```

it says 2 type argument expected.

I don't know if it helps you or not but some one told me I have to use join in Kotlin

THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWERS :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my Question

We have to use Join in query:

```
//for single info
 @Query("SELECT `transaction`.increase, `transaction`.decrease, bank.bank_name From `transaction` JOIN bank WHERE `transaction`.bank_id=:key ")
    fun joinTables(key: Long): LiveData<TransactionAndBank>?



//for list of info
 @Query("SELECT `transaction`.increase, `transaction`.decrease,`transaction`.type, bank.bank_name From `transaction` JOIN bank WHERE `transaction`.bank_id=:key ")
    fun joinAllTables(key: Long): LiveData<List<TransactionAndBank>>
```

I had to place it In TransactionDAO

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65633651/14976321)

Answer (score 1):

ListAdaper can only accept one data model however you can add multiple items using another class like `Sealed Class`

```
sealed class DataItem {
    abstract val id: Long

    data class TransactionItem(val transaction: Transaction): DataItem() {
        override val id = transaction.transId
    }

    object Empty: DataItem() {
        override val id = Long.MIN_VALUE
    }
}
```

and deal with this only class in your ListAdapter for your code you will need to apply this changes

```
    class TransactionHistory() :
    ListAdapter<DataItem, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(BillDiffCallback()) {
    private val ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY = 0
    private val ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM_TRANSACTION = 1
    private val ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM_BANK = 2

    private val adapterScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

    /**
     * DO NOT USE .submit(), use the method bellow
     */

    fun addTransactionsAndBanks(transactionList: List<Transaction>?, bankList: List<Bank>?) {
        adapterScope.launch {
            val transactionItems: List<DataItem> = when {
                transactionList == null || transactionList.isEmpty() -> listOf(DataItem.Empty)
                else -> transactionList.map { DataItem.TransactionItem(it) }
            }
            val bankItems: List<DataItem> = when {
                bankList == null || bankList.isEmpty() -> listOf(DataItem.Empty)
                else -> bankList.map { DataItem.BankItem(it) }
            }

            val items = transactionItems + bankItems
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                submitList(items)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM_TRANSACTION -> ViewHolder.from(parent)
            ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM_BANK -> ViewHolder.from(parent)
            ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY -> EmptyViewHolder.from(parent)
            else -> throw ClassCastException("Unknown viewType $viewType")
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is ViewHolder -> {
                when (val item = getItem(position)) {
                    is DataItem.TransactionItem -> holder.bind(item.transaction, clickListener)
                    is DataItem.BankItem -> holder.bind2(item.bank, clickListener)
                }
            }
            is EmptyViewHolder -> holder.bind()
        }
    }

    lateinit var clickListener: AdapterListener2
    fun setOnclickListener(listener: AdapterListener2) {
        clickListener = listener
    }


    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return when (getItem(position)) {
            is DataItem.Empty -> ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY
            is DataItem.TransactionItem -> ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM_TRANSACTION
            is DataItem.BankItem -> ITEM_VIEW_TYPE_ITEM_BANK
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder
    private constructor(val binding: ItemUserTransactionListBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: Transaction, adapterListener2: AdapterListener2) {
            binding.transaction = item
            binding.clickListener = adapterListener2
            binding.executePendingBindings()
            if (item.type == "payPayment") {
                binding.transactionStatus.text = "برداخت قسط"
            } else if (item.type == "decrease") {
                binding.transactionStatus.text = "برداشت"
            } else if (item.type == "increase") {
                binding.transactionStatus.text = "واریز"
            }

            if (item.decrease == null) {
                binding.amount.text = item.increase
            } else {
                binding.amount.text = item.decrease
            }
        }

        fun bind2(item2: Bank, adapterListener2: AdapterListener2) {
            binding.bankInfo = item2
            binding.clickListener = adapterListener2
            binding.executePendingBindings()
        }

        companion object {
            fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
                val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                val binding = ItemUserTransactionListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
                return ViewHolder(binding)
            }
        }
    }
}

class EmptyViewHolder private constructor(val binding: ItemUserTransactionListBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    fun bind() {
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }

    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): EmptyViewHolder {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding = ItemUserTransactionListBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
            return EmptyViewHolder(binding)
        }
    }
}


class BillDiffCallback : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<DataItem>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: DataItem, newItem: DataItem): Boolean {
        return oldItem.id == newItem.id
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: DataItem, newItem: DataItem): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}

class AdapterListener2(
    val clickListener: (id: Long?) -> Unit,
    val deleteListener: (category: Transaction) -> Unit

) {
    fun onclick(transaction: Transaction) = clickListener(transaction.userId)
    fun onDeleteClick(userInfo: Transaction) = deleteListener(userInfo)

}

sealed class DataItem {
    abstract val id: Long

    data class TransactionItem(val transaction: Transaction) : DataItem() {
        override val id = transaction.transId
    }

    data class BankItem(val bank: Bank) : DataItem() {
        override val id = bank.bankId
    }

    object Empty : DataItem() {
        override val id = Long.MIN_VALUE
    }
}
```

Comment: so WHERE should I put my second data class,I think your code is all about Transaction class

Comment: You need to create a `DataItem` sealed class and use it in `ListAdapter` also change the diffUtil item callback to use dataItem class,

Comment: The second data class "Empty class" will added when you call `addTransactions` method if the list is null or empty

Comment: Please check the update of Question

Comment: I Updated my answer, could you please check it again ?

Comment: Thanks for working on my project but it still says unresolved reference list in and transaction and Bank

Comment: Can you post the error message please ?

Comment: ok 1.Unresolved reference: list   2.Unresolved reference: it  3.ype mismatch.
Required:
(Mutable)List<Transaction!>?
Found:
List<DataItem>  4.classifier 'TransactionItem' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialized here   AND SO ON   I didn't make any changes to the project when I clone it these errors apeared

Comment: and one more None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.

Comment: I Updated my answer again

Comment: this is my email:   amirrajaezadeh1383@gmail.com   please send me an email and let me know if u wish to email me or not

Comment: there is something wrong in Binding Utils

Comment: @AmirAndroidDeveloper yes sir you need to use `addTransactionsAndBanks` method, try to adjust your bindingUtils class

Comment: Yes  instead of submit list I have to use addTransactionAndBanks. I will give it a try. THANKS FOR YOUR RESPONSE

Comment: Still have any issues or your question is answered?

Comment: Actually I have added that in utils  but after that there was error that says I need to pass transaction and bank  I added list1: Transaction and list2: Bank. If you can solve that issue and run project on your own android studeo. Thanks a million 

Answer (score 0):

You can build the list based on only a single data source. If you want to have multiple data sources, you should create a third data model and add the other two models in it.

```
data class ListData(val transaction : Transaction , val Bank : Bank)
```

ListView/Recycler view will create number of list items based on the list of objects passed.

```
ListAdapter<ListData, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I don't want to create new class. I am trying hard to do some thing in adapter it self. Your answer is a acceptable solution I will try it thanks.

Comment: Can you please post a third data model class code if you have? You know, I do not have any idea how to call to model class in third data class.

Comment: @AmirAndroidDeveloper Check the updated answer.

Comment: check update of Question